# Dynamically change the choices in a wx.ComboBox()

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I didn't find a better way to change the different choices in a wx.ComboBox() than swap the old ComboBox with a new one. Is there a better way?

Oerjan Pettersen

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#20_combobox.py

import wx
import wx.lib.inspection

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.p1 = wx.Panel(self)
        lst = ['1','2','3']
        self.st = wx.ComboBox(self.p1, -1, choices = lst, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)

        self.st.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.text_return)


    def text_return(self, event):
        lst = ['3','4']
        self.st = wx.ComboBox(self.p1, -1, choices = lst, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, '20_combobox.py')
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
#    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[wx.ComboBox](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_combo_box.html) derives from [wx.ItemContainer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_item_container.html), which has methods for [Appending](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_item_container.html#a8fdc0090e3eabc762ff0e49e925f8bc4), [Clearing](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_item_container.html#aea621d4fdfbc3a06bf24dcc97304e2c1), [Inserting](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_item_container.html#a8844cacec8509fe6e637c6f85eb8b395) and [Deleting](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_item_container.html#a0e8379f41e9d7b912564000828140a19) items, all of these methods are available on wx.ComboBox.

One way to do what you want would be to define the text_return() method as follows:

```
def text_return(self, event):
    self.st.Clear()
    self.st.Append('3')
    self.st.Append('4')
```

Comment: or self.sf.AppendItems(['3', '4'])

Comment: @Toni Cool I was looking for that - but for some reason that function isn't documented.

Comment: Thanks. AppendItems is in the new docs, but not in the old ones.

Comment: Docs could be reached at http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ItemContainer.html#ItemContainer.Clear

Comment: Update : doc links are down

Comment: The internal structure of the docs has changed, so the document at that link no longer exists.  You can still get to the docs for that method by drilling down from the root page: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/main.html