# Python 2.7.8 TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, unicode, wxpython

I am running python version 2.7.8. I am storing project titles in a sqlite database that I am trying to import into a combobox. When I try and import the project titles from the sqlite database and import them into the combobox I get this error: TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Here is my code:

main.py

```
from EvDB import EvDB
import wx
from ProjectsPanel import ProjectsPanel

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """ We simply derive a new class of Frame. """
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title=title, size=(650,725))

        # Create Database Tables
        self.db = EvDB(self)
        self.db.createTbls()

        main = wx.Panel(self)

        self.projectsPg = ProjectsPanel(main, -1)

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.mainSizer.Add(self.projectsPg, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)


        main.SetAutoLayout(True)
        main.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.mainSizer.Fit(main)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

        self.UserID = 1
        rows = self.db.getProjects(self.UserID)

        print(rows)
        print(str(rows))

        self.projectsPg.cb.Value(rows)

app = wx.App(False)
```

ProjectsPanel.py

```
import wx
from EvDB import EvDB
import sqlite3 as lite

class ProjectsPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, ID)

        self.db = lite.connect('evDB.db')
        self.cur = self.db.cursor()
        self.db2 = EvDB(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # the combobox Control
        self.userProjects = ['Before1','Before2', 'Before3', 'Before4']
        self.cb = wx.ComboBox(self, value='New', choices=self.userProjects, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)

        sizer.Add(self.cb, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        # Setting Layouts
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self)
```

EvDB.py

```
import sqlite3 as lite

class EvDB():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.db = lite.connect('evDB.db')
        self.cur = self.db.cursor()

    def createTbls(self):

        self.db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Projects
                        (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
                        Title varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
                        DateCreated DATE);''')

        self.db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User_x_Project
                        (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
                        UserID INT DEFAULT NULL,
                        ProjectID INT DEFAULT NULL);''')


    def getProjects(self,userID):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT Title FROM User_x_Project, Projects WHERE User_x_Project.UserID = "+str(userID)+" AND User_x_Project.ProjectID = Projects.ID;")
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()

        return rows
```

the print results: [(u'Tests',), (u'Test1',), (u'Test2',), (u'Test3',)]

How do I add the titles stored in my sqlite database to my combobox?

Thank you for any and all help!

EDIT: Here is my entire traceback

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/main.py
[(u'Tests',), (u'Test1',), (u'Test2',), (u'Test3',)]
[(u'Tests',), (u'Test1',), (u'Test2',), (u'Test3',)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'Small editor')
  File "C:/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/main.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.projectsPg.cb.Value(rows)
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Update your question and add the entire traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.projectsPg.cb` is a ComboBox object, and `Value` is a property. If you access the property without assignment it will return a string (or unicode). You can't call it.

If you want to set a value to the combox, use property assignment ([`ComboBox.Value =`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ComboBox-class.html#Value)), or [`ComboxBox.SetValue`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ComboBox-class.html#SetValue):

In addition to that, the `rows` returned by [`Cursor.fetchall`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchall) is a list of tuples. You need to fetch the first one. (In the following example, I omitted return row count check for brevity)

```
self.projectsPg.cb.Value = rows[0][0]

# OR

self.projectsPg.cb.SetValue(rows[0][0])
```

Comment: This fixed the 'unicode' error therefore you get the answer... but self.projectsPg.cb.Value = rows[0][0] and self.projectsPg.cb.SetValue(rows[0][0]) only shows the title in the "blank space" of the combobox it does not repopulate the combobox's choices.

Comment: FYI I found the answer to repopulate the combobox's choices [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682923/dynamically-change-the-choices-in-a-wx-combobox)